# If $A\in \sigma(A_1,\cdots, A_n)$ and $A$ is independent of $A_1$, prove $A\in \sigma(A_2,\cdots, A_n)$.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

I am not quite sure the whether following statement is correct:

If $A\in \sigma(A_1,\cdots, A_n)$ and $A$ is independent of $A_1$, then $A\in \sigma(A_2,\cdots, A_n)$. I can see that the sets in $\sigma(A_1,\cdots, A_n)$ which are independent of $A$ form a $\sigma$ algebra. But I just cannot prove it is indeed $\sigma(A_2,\cdots, A_n)$.

It looks quite reasonable, since intuitively $A$ is in $\sigma(A_2,\cdots, A_n)$ means $A$ can only be affected by $A_2,\cdots, A_n$. So I guess this should be true.

Comment: Independence requires a probabilty measure. But the conclusion has nothing to do with measures. So the question hardly makes sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for comment. I see, this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(A)=0$ but $A \neq \emptyset$. Let $n=2, A_2=\emptyset$ and $A=A_1$. This is a counter-example.